# Ошибка в макросе суммирования

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Программа должна заполнить выделенную ячейку и 4 ячейки ниже цифрами от 1 до 5, в пятую снизу ячейку записать сумму этих чисел.

```
  Sub ЗаписьСумма()
    Sheets("Лист1").Select
    Sheets("Лист1").Name = "myWorksheet"
    x = ActiveCell.Column
    y = ActiveCell.Row
    y0 = y - 1
    For iCounter = 0 To 4
        myWorksheet.Range(x, y + iCounter).Value = (iCounter + 1)
    Next
    myWorksheet.Range(x, y + iCounter + 1).Value = 5 * 6 / 2
    End Sub
```

При выполнении этого кода возникает ошибка 424. Чем она вызвана?

Answer (score 1):

**Ошибка 1**. *myWorksheet...* - неправильное обращение к листу, нужно:

```
Sheets("myWorksheet")...
```

Т.е.: обратиться по имени к конкретному листу из коллекции листов книги.

В редакторе *VBA* в дереве проекта можно увидеть название модуля листа:

```
Лист1(myWorksheet)
```

В скобках - видимое имя листа, первым написано внутреннее имя. Внутреннее имя можно использовать без привязки. Для показанного примера:

```
Sheets("myWorksheet").Range("A1")...
Лист1.Range("A1")...
```

Внутреннее имя можно менять в свойствах листа. Если имя используется в коде, лучше применять латиницу.

**Ошибка 2**. *Range(x,y)* - неправильно. Варианты:

```
Range("A1"), Range("A1:B15"), Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(15,2)), Cells(y,x)
```

Если эти ошибки исправить, код будет работать. Но...

' ============================

Активируете лист, переименовываете его... Дальше - лотерея - какая ячейка будет активной? Правильнее: указывать ячейку. При этом не обязательно активировать лист. Но если ячейку нужно обязательно активировать, то и лист должен быть активным.

Переменные нужно декларировать и указывать их тип. Без указания типа переменные по умолчанию имеют тип *Variant* и занимают максимум памяти. Переменным желательно давать имена, по которым понятно, за что они отвечают. Счетчики обычно именуют одной буквой.

Пример кода (адреса ячеек записаны в разных вариантах, 0,25 тоже для примера)

```
Sub ЗаписьСумма()
Dim dSum As Double
Dim lRow As Long, lClmn As Long
Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Лист1")
        .Name = "myWorksheet"
        lRow = .Range("D5").Row
        lClmn = .Cells(5, 4).Column

        For i = 0 To 4
            .Range("D" & lRow + i).Value = i + 0.25
            dSum = dSum + i + 0.25
        Next i

        .Cells(lRow + 5, lClmn).Value = dSum
        .Activate
    End With

    MsgBox "Сумма: " & dSum, 64, "РЕЗУЛЬТАТ"
End Sub
```